# set a thread to run a argument that takes a variable that takes more variables C++ Multitreading

Tags: c++, multithreading

First off i know the title is horribly worded I counldn't think of a better way to phrase it. Bassically I am using sfml and running multiple windows. I have a function that runs through a vector and that works like the while loop typically would. As the vector gets big windows update slowly to fix that I am trying to impliment multithreading. I have never tried to use multithreading before and this is probably a easy question but none of the basic tutorials I found coverd it.

this is the function im trying to run `WindowArray[i]->setPosition(Gravity(KeyArray[i], WindowArray[i]))`.

If I do it like this it gets errors

```
std::thread thread1;
thread1 = thread(WindowArray[i]->setPosition, Gravity(KeyArray[i], WindowArray[i]));
```

How should I go about doing this?

something to put in a compiler

```cpp
class NewKey {
public:
    sf::Image Img;
    sf::Texture Tex;
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    sf::Vector2i Velocity;
    sf::Vector2i Acceleration;
    void StepVelocity() {
        Velocity += Acceleration;
        Acceleration = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
    }
};
vector <NewKey> KeyArray;
vector <unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow>> WindowArray;
unsigned maxThreads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
int activeThreads;
int dropRate;
sf::Vector2i Gravity(NewKey& Key, unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow>& window) {
    dropRate = 10;
    Key.Acceleration += sf::Vector2i(0, dropRate);
    Key.StepVelocity;
    sf::Vector2i Result = sf::Vector2i(window->getPosition() + Key.Velocity);
    return Result;
}

void StepWindows()
{
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < WindowArray.size(); i++)
    {
        while (!(activeThreads + 1) >= maxThreads)
        {
            activeThreads++;
            std::thread thread1;
            thread1 = thread(WindowArray[i]->setActive(true));
            thread1 = thread(WindowArray[i]->setPosition, Gravity(KeyArray[i], WindowArray[i]));
            activeThreads--;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    unique_ptr<sf::RenderWindow> window = make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>();
    WindowArray.emplace_back(window);
    StepWindows();
}
```

Comment: WindowArray is my array of renderwindows and keyarray is a array of a class with sprites, textures. things like that

Comment: You should go about this by following instructions in stackoverflow.com's [help] for creating a [mre], first.